# Mongoose findOne() matching all Id's from an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a small problem with the mongoose query.
I need to fetch a document that is uniquely based on an array with 2 `ObjectId`
fields. It's unique because the members' pairs it will match in only one document

[image]

I need to match both ObjectId's in **members**  and then fetch the document

*here is my route:*

```
router
  .route('/convWith/:firstUser/:secondUser')
  .get(protect, myConversationWithUser);
```

*this is my controller query:*

```
  const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
    members: { $all: [req.params.firstUser, req.params.secondUser] },
  });
```

***Schema***

```
const conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    members: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);
module.exports = Conversation;
```

I get both of my params right but the findOne function returns `null` and it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong here guys? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show your schema?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated the post with my Conversation schema

Comment: you need to convert your input id from string to objectId `[mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.firstUser), mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.secondUser)]` because you did not specified any type in members array in schema.

Comment: Oh my god, such a silly mistake! Thank you brother for spotting that for me.

Answer (score 1):

To find multiple users

```
 Conversation.find( { name: { $in: [ "User1", "User2" ] } } )
```

Comment: Check this query is working in your project?